# How to properly encode XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have this code to return XML to a user in a web browser.

```
public FileResult GetReportParameters(string reportId)
{
    string parameters = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\r\n" +
        LoadXml(reportId).ToString();

    return File(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(parameters), "application/xml");
}
```

LoadXML loads XML froma database and returns it as an XElement object.  Strings in C# are UTF-16.  So to make sure everything stays encoded correctly I specified UTF-16 for the encoding and used the Unicode encoding to convert the text to a byte[] array for the File constructor.

When I run this from Visual Studio it works fine and displays in IE's XML visualizer.  However, after I publish this to our web server it doesn't work and IE gives the following error.

> The XML page cannot be displayed  Cannot view XML input using XSL
>   style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh
>   button, or try again later.
>
> ---
>
> A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing
>   resource

I was able to get it to display in IE's XML visuallizer by using UTF-8 instead.

```
public FileResult GetReportParameters(string reportId)
{
    string parameters = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" +
        LoadXml(reportId).ToString();

    return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters), "application/xml");
}
```

However, won't any unicode characters be displayed wrong?  What is the correct way for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: UTF-8 is also Unicode, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8.  I'm not sure why you think you need to use UTF-16, but UTF-8 is what I typically use and what I typically see others using.

Comment: I read somewhere that c# strings are stored as unicode and for System.Text.Encoding.Unicode the docs says 'Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order'.  So I inferred that's how c# stores strings and I should use UTF-16.  I suppose it doesn't really matter how c# stores strings internally.  However, if I encode in UTF-16 (with Encoding.Unicode) and tell IE to use UTF-16, shouldn't it work?  In any case, it appears unicode strings can be correctly encoded in various ways.  So if UTF8 works then I'll just use UTF8 for this.

Comment: Oh, did some more reading.  The XML standard says to use UTF8 encoding.  So using a different encoding can cause the program reading the XML to not even be able to read the xml attribute that says what encoding was used.

Answer (score 0):

I would try saving the file that your code produces and opening it in PSPad in HexMode, or another editor that lets you look at the individual bytes.  Perhaps IE only looks at the byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file and ignores your "encoding=UTF16" attribute.  If there is no BOM, the XML standard dictates that the encoding is UTF8 and most software recognizes that standard.